# Why does special character create extra space when combined?

Tags: html, special-characters

I have a line of text that contains the french word 'péférez'.

When I insert it like this...

```html
<p>pr&eacute;f&eacute;rez</p>
```

I get a full line of extra space between the 'f' and second &eacute.

How is this possible?  I have done everything I can to strip any extra formatting - there is none there.

What is happening here?

Screen grab

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem. I don't believe I'm asking, but can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: If it's an encoding problem, try with utf8 by adding this in your `<head>`: `<meta charset="utf-8" />` (seems weird though...)

Comment: Looks ok to me. Screenshot should help.

Comment: Screen shot added.

Comment: Also, the <meta> was always on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was related to the custom font I was using.  Removed it.  Problem solved.  Thanks for the input all!

Answer (score 0):

Add `<meta charset="utf-8"`inside `<head>` this problem is caused by the lack of characters used by your browser, which is specified by `<meta charset="utf-8"`.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  That tag is in the page header.  There is no css being applied.  Just a straight <p> tag.